# Is there any other way to monitor VAAI stats on ESXI without using ESXTOP command?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, esxi

I'm performing Automation on the ESXI6.5 for VAAI stats monitoring.But i'm facing problem in running ESXTOP command in batch mode due to which i'm not getting the output.I've tried all the possible solutions available on the internet but the problem is still there.

Is there any other way to get VAAI status in ESXI other than using ESXTOP command?

Thank you in Advance,

Arshpreet

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. However there are several ways to obtain the ESXTOP output other than being SSHed to the host. There's RESXTOP that's available as part of vSphere CLI and PowerCLI has the Get-EsxTop cmdlet. (Note: Get-EsxTop requires being connected directly to the host and not a vCenter Server)